# Saving jQuery Selections to Variables Behave Differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-selectors

I am currently practicing jQuery.
My code is simply an unordered list that got 10 list items. Each Item got a different movie name and I save the selection `$('li')` to a variable called `$listItems` While trying the `.on method`, I encountered something awkward. My code simply appends todays date next to each list item when a user `mouseover` the list item then with `mouseout` it removes the date. It is working fine for the list items that I wrote in the HTML file but it doesn't work properly for list items I added using javascript. However, this ONLY happens when I create both the `mouseover` and the `mouseout` on the variable `$listItems`. When I use the normal `$('li')` selector, it works fine for items I added via HTML and those added via javascript.

Hope my code illustrates what I am trying to understand::

```js
/*

This DOESN'T append the date to list items added via JAVASCRIPT on mouseover 
    when the $('li') selection is saved to a variable, however it works fine if I used $('li') on mouseover and mouseout...
*/

$(document).ready(function(){
var $listItems = $('li');

//Add items to the unordered list using javascript
    var mainUL = document.getElementById('list');
 var newMovies = ['Fantastic Four','Spectre','Fast and Furious','Jupiter Ascending','007', 'Zero Hour', 'The Runner', 'Brave','Never Back Down'];
 var newMovieEntry = document.createElement('li');
 var newMovieName;

 newMovies.forEach( function(movie) {
  newMovieEntry = document.createElement('li');
  newMovieName = document.createTextNode(movie);
  newMovieEntry.appendChild(newMovieName);
  newMovieEntry.textContent = movie;
  mainUL.appendChild(newMovieEntry);
      });

//Create date, day, month and year.
var date = new Date();
 var day;
 var month;
 var year = date.getFullYear();
 var dayNames = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
 var monthNames = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
 day = dayNames[date.getDay()];
 month = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
 
//Append formatted date on mouseover.
 $listItems.on('mouseover', function() {

  $(this).append(" <em>(" + date.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + year + ")</em>");

 });

//Remove formatted date on mouseout
 $listItems.on('mouseout', function(){
  $(this).children('em').remove();
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="junk.js"></script>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Hello world!</title>
 <style type="text/css">

  ul {
   
   text-align: center;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: -moz-flex;
   display: -ms-flex;
   display: -o-flex;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
  }

  li {
   width: 60%;
   border: 5px solid;
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 10px;
   line-height: 2em;
  }

  .newly-added {
   background-color: #00ff00 !important;
   color: #000 !important;
  }

  .royalblue {
   background-color: #405BFF;
  }

  .hazyorange {
   background-color: #FD8239;
  }

  .lightgreen {
   background-color: #76FF76;
  }

   .watermelon {
   background-color: #FC4343 !important;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <ul id="list">
  <h1>Movies List</h1>
  <li>Star Wars</li>
  <li>Saving Private Ryan</li>
  <li>Bridge of Spies</li>
  <li>Avatar</li>
  <li>Fury</li>
  <li>Home Alone</li>
  <li>Snowden</li>
  <li>Inception</li>
  <li>Wolf of Wall Street</li>
  <li>Legend</li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Why jQuery selection behaves differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store the list items present in the HTML into your variable and add afterwards new items. This does not update your variable, so the added items are not receiving the function of your .on method.

Comment: Ah so after I add new list items via javascript I should reassign my variable to the same jquery selection again in order to include them.